# Why can't I directly reference my String enum?

Tags: java, enums

I thought I would try to start a minecraft mod today. I was going to use an enum class to store thing like my version and modid.

```
public enum Reference {

   MODID("farming"),
   VERSION("1.8.0-0.0.1");

   private String value;

    Reference(String string) {

        String value = string;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return value;

    }

}
```

The override to the `toString` method was an idea that did not work. It still complains that it wants a string but I am returning `Reference` which is an incompatible type since it wants a `String`.

Here is the rest of the main class.

```
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MODID , version = Reference.VERSION)
public class FarmingMod
{

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {



    }


}
```

The part I am trying to figure out is the annotation `@Mod`. I took a look at the code for the annotation. It says it will accept a single String only.

What I am not wrapping my head around is my enum class is not compatible. I am returning a String in each of my enums.

What could the issue be?

Comment: I don't know about  minecraft mod, but why don't you try 'Reference.MODID.toString()'  once the annotation accepts only string and not a Enum

Comment: @calazans It's not a constant expression so it doesn't compile for the annotation value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the source code](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/FML/blob/master/src/main/java/net/minecraftforge/fml/common/Mod.java), `Mod#modid` expects a `String`

```
String modid();
```

but you are providing a `Reference`

```
@Mod(modid = Reference.MODID ...)
```

You seem to think that Java will implicitly convert something to a `String` if you override its `toString` method. It won't.

You won't be able to do

```
modid = Reference.MODID.toString()
```

because annotation attributes, more or less, expect constant expressions, and method invocations are not constant expressions. You won't be able to solve this with `enum`s. You can declare and use a `static final` variable

```
// in some Constants class
public static final String MODID = "farming"; // constant variable/expression
```

and

```
@Mod(modid = Constants.MODID)
```

You also can't use

```
@Mod(modid = Reference.MODID.value)
```

because the field access `.value` is also not a constant expression.

Comment: So if I remove the overridden method it should work?

Comment: @ianc1215 What? No. It will never work. Java expects a `String` and you give it a `Reference`.

Comment: Ah I understand now. So I am better off dropping the enum and just delclaring constants in a standard class? I thought I was on to something with the enums. What was confusing me was my enums worked fine in the first method body. Is it because the @Mod is an annotation that I must have a constant?